# What is needed to set up a PHP development and production environment?

Tags: php, html, web-applications, development-environment, php-5.2

I have inherited a little database driven PHP site.

I am a C# programmer, and have almost zero experience with PHP, although I have great experience with databases and some html / web design.

My boss tasked me to create a staging and production environment for this php site.

**Environment:** Win 7, 64 bit. Sql Server 2012. PHP 5.2. There are a couple hundred users. We only the need the site to work with explorer. Dreamweaver latest version. There would not be more than 1 user working on the project at a time.

1. Which code repository should we go with?
2. For now we are not going with a code repository yet. Besides having separate folders for staging and production, would we need any other folder structure?
3. I also would be very grateful for your help in formulating the right questions to ensure that I have everything that a "professional" developer needs to set this up.

Comment: How is it, that you have 976reps but.....

Comment: A professional developer can accomplish their job with nothing but a shell prompt. Devel environments are simply there to make their job easier. A rockstar developer can work without even the shell. Godly developers simply wave magnets over a harddrive and flip bits as they need to.

Comment: @MarcB i definitely wouldnt be able to accomplish my job with nothing but a shell prompt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.. You're looking for http://www.xampp.org, its an all in one solution :)
You can however customize the environment once installed.

Even the PRO's use it :) because it makes it all very simple and quick :)

Comment: EDITED: It doesn't have a CVS/SCM bundled. But I would recommend GIT for a team environment mostly due to their branching feature otherwise all are good :)

Comment: would you recommend this on a windows system and can it do php 5.2?

Comment: No problem, and yes i was specifically recommending this for windows.. because i am also using a similar environment as you need :) and xampp has been very helpful, plus its cross browser so i can also use the same thing in uBuntu aswell :) I cannot confirm the latest version of PHP (but it is latest stable so something like PHP 5.4.x). If you need older releases you can check out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/